# XSL Duplicate Merge and convert attributes to tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I have a xml that looks like below.  tag c67 and tag c57 is duplicating with different attributes. This is happens if the tag is   multi value.

```
<data>
   <c67 m="103">101</c67>
   <c67 m="104">DELEUNIQUEID12311150</c67>
   <c67 m="105">002500-404</c67>
   <c67 m="107">0505-095916</c67>
   <c67 m="108">0505</c67>
   <c67 m="203">DELEUNIQUEID1112354121</c67>
   <c67 m="205">0000030</c67>
   <c67 m="284">1204896941</c67>
   <c67 m="303">0000030</c67>
   <c57 m="01">0000020</c57>
   <c57 m="02">NO</c57>
   <c62>NO</c62>
   <c63>TR</c63>
</data>
```

I need to transform all the duplicates tags into one object with  children like below. The tag will always have attributes. if i have tag c67 appearing more than ones . One object will be created with tag c67 and all the repeating tags will be children of the tag. like below. See tag c67 and c57 . The tags are dynamic and are not static. On this instance c67 and c57 were produced . on another instance it can be c47 or C31 or any other. Am looking for dynamic solution to always produce xml like below whenever i have repeating tags with attributes

```
<data>
   <c67>
      <m103>101</m103>
      <m67>DELEUNIQUEID12311150</m67>
      <m105>002500-404</m105>
      <m205>0000030</m205>
   </c67>
   <c57>
      <m02>0000020 </m02>
      <m01>NO</m01>
  </c57>
   <c62>NO</c62>
   <c63>TR</c63>
</data>
```

I have the below xslt which is pretty close but generates array instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="m"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:element name="m{.}"><xsl:value-of select="../node()" /></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="m">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(@*)">
                <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" /></xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Generates something like below.

```
<data>  
<c67>
      <m9>DELEUNIQUEID1231151</m9>
   </c67>
   <c67>
      <m94>QWEWEQWQWE</m94>
   </c67>
   <c67>
      <m95>111</m95>
   </c67>
   <c67>
      <m101>0200830000</m101>
   </c67>
   <c67>
      <m102>404</m102>
   </c67>
   <c57>
      <m01>0000020 </m01>
   </c57>
    <c57>
        <m02>No</m02>
   </c57>

 </data>
```

How can i achieve the  above results using xslt

Comment: Your business rules are not clear. Why are some values used en others not?

Comment: it was just an example of what is expected. That is why some values are left out

Comment: Well, the example is misleading and it's not clear what are you trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I have edited the question to  bring more clarity

Comment: This has now become a *grouping* question. The preferred method of grouping in XSLT 1.0 is described here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. If you cannot apply this to your situation, post your best attempt. -- Hint: define your key along the lines of `<xsl:key name="elem-by-name" match="*[@*]" use="name()" />`.

Comment: BTW, it is still not clear whether the discrepancies between the input and the expected result are intentional.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. Perhaps you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <c67>
            <xsl:for-each select="c67">
                <xsl:element name="m{@m}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </c67>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::c67)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given your input example, this would return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <c67>
    <m103>101</m103>
    <m104>DELEUNIQUEID12311150</m104>
    <m105>002500-404</m105>
    <m107>0505-095916</m107>
    <m108>0505</m108>
    <m203>DELEUNIQUEID1112354121</m203>
    <m205>0000030</m205>
    <m284>1204896941</m284>
    <m303>0000030</m303>
  </c67>
  <c57 m="01">0000020</c57>
  <c57 m="02">NO</c57>
  <c62>NO</c62>
  <c63>TR</c63>
</data>
```